24.04.1 LTS Package System is Broken (python3-pil_10.2.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb)
I just ran the 24.04.1 LTS upgrade which couldn't install the python3-pil_10.2.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb package.
My current problem is that apt seems to be broken as it has a dependency that i can not fulfill.
Whenever i try to get a package with apt i get
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-pil : Depends: python3 (< 3.11) but 3.12.3-0ubuntu2 is to be installed

apt --fix-broken install will result in
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python3-pil
Suggested packages:
  python-pil-doc
The following packages will be upgraded:
  python3-pil
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/452 kB of archives.
After this operation, 118 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 312582 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3-pil_10.2.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-pil:amd64 (10.2.0-1ubuntu1) over (9.0.1-1ubuntu0.3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-pil_10.2.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to stat './usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/BdfFontFile.py' (which was about to be installed): Input/output error
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-pil_10.2.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Is there a way to solve this ?

The package looks okay (https://packages.ubuntu.com/noble-updates/python3-pil) but I note a IO error message; ie. Input/output error on your system.. thus I'd explore that, ie. unable to stat './usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/BdfFontFile.py'  and any clues in your system logs (do you have disk error, what file-system is it on (ie. any problem there) etc..)  .. ie. I don't see a dep error BUT a fs or machine problem I'd explore

Please, try to be more clear in your question. Use a precise and concise language.

@guiverc Thank you you were absolutely right, it really was the ssd starting to fail. a check revealed a lot of bad sectors and damaged files. Guess i will need to re-install anyway now but at least i can save that what is left though.
